# Shapefile layer not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers

I have a polygon layer which is listed at the top of the layers panel, however it is showing underneath other layers on the map canvas.  It is in the right location but despite being at the top of the layers list is underneath everything on the canvas and I cant figure out why.  What should I do?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, click the mouse on your layer and move it up, move all the layers to the right place for you ... if I understand you correctly, please clarify your task ...

Comment: Because in the layer window it is placed below other layers. Just move it to the top in the layer window.

Comment: Hi,  The layer is in the right place, it is at the very top of the layer stack, so I am assuming it should be visible at the top, but instead it is only visible when you uncheck the google map layer

Comment: Do you just have two layers - the polygons and Google Maps? How have you added Google Maps?

Comment: No, there are lots more layers.  Google maps is added via the old web map plugin as we are still currently using version 2.18.  I have never had this issue before

Comment: Can you share a screenshot for layer panel ?

Comment: If you click "zoom to layer" in the context menu does it relocate your view? Perhaps it's an SRID mismatch?

Answer (score 5):

One possible issue is that the Layer Order is being set by the Layer Order panel.

To check this, open the Layer Order Panel:

```
View> Panels (near the bottom)> Layer Order Panel
```

Then make sure the "Control rendering order is not ticked, and the Layer Order panel is greyed out.

Like so:

[image]